# Sending python Object from one script to another

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I have two python scripts, one runs in 64bit environment and another runs in 32bit environment (because of some COM Objects to use).

I want to send python object from one script to another and perform some operations.
What can be the best way of sending python object from one script to another ?

Environment :
Python 2.7 32bit and 64bit
OS : Windows

Thanks

Comment: I think standard practice would be to just [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) it and send it across.

Comment: Or one can use Pyro https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4

Comment: As @DaoWen suggests the simplest way is to pickle it. It's also not just a case of sending an object between scripts this requires sockets more than likely as one program can not communicate with another across machines (or Python's case across Python interpreter instances)

Comment: multiprocessing does much for you: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html